# jquery get the input file value on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, file-upload, onchange

I try to get the upload value when the `input field`'s `change event` occurs

But I get this value on Chrome,

```
C:\fakepath\winnie-the-pooh.jpg
```

So I split the `\` and the the last item in the array.

jquery,

```
$("#upload").change(function(){

    var fragment = $("#upload").val();
    var array_fragment = fragment.split('\/');
    alert($(array_fragment).last()[0]);

});
```

But I still get `C:\fakepath\winnie-the-pooh.jpg` instead of `winnie-the-pooh.jpg` on Chrome.

How can I make it worked?

the html,

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="upload"/>
```

Comment: there is no way to get the fullpath in chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split on `\`, not `/`:

```
var array_fragment = fragment.split('\\');
```

Ideally though, you'd split on either. Fortunately, `split` takes a regular expression:

```
var array_fragment = fragment.split(/\\|\//);
```

That regex basically means "`\` or `/`"—the pipe operator, `|`, is the "or", and the `/` characters at the start and end signify that a regular expression is in between.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need jQuery to operate with arrays. Also, the file path may not contain a slash, e.g. on Firefox. Consider this example:

```
var filename = $("#upload").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, "");
alert(filename);
```

This is better than wrapping an array with jQuery just to get its last element.

Comment: If there's no slash, then `split` will return an array of one element (the entire input), so the last element will still be the file name. That said, I do like this answer. Shorter is generally better.

Answer (score 0):

you can read my post i had asked months ago::
[my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854035/image-preview-before-upload-in-ie-and-chrome)

based upon your requirements you can derive something from that post!!!